# Representing vector field with ovals and color

Tags: python, matlab, plot, field

I have a vector field which shows the direction of some ovals in different positions with different aspect ratio. I could plot it in Matlab by the below script:

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(1:size(nx,1), 1:size(nx,2));
  quiver(X,Y, nx, ny, 'ShowArrowHead', 'Off','linewidth',1);
set(qh, 'Color', 'k');
```

Where X and Y show positions in space and `nx` and `ny` show orientation of the ovals. Information on aspect ratio is inside `nx` and `ny`. So, `sqrt(nx.^2+ny.^2)` gives a magnitude that is between 0 and 1. If this magnitude is zero in some points, it means that in those points we have circle instead of ovals. If it is equal to 1 it means we have an elongated oval. 
But it looks very basic. I want to have something in which each point in space I have a rotated oval where the color shows the aspect ratio. How can I do this in Matlab or python?

Comment: This is indeed an interesting question. Why did it get -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a grid of ellipse and apply a rotation matrix to each of them. Here is a minimal example:

```matlab
[X0, Y0] = meshgrid(0:5,0:5);  % the initial grid
a        = 0.2;                % horizontal radius
b        = 0.4;                % vertical radius
t        = 0:0.01:2*pi;        
rotmat   = @(phi) [cos(phi) sin(phi); -sin(phi) cos(phi)]; % A 2D anonymous rotation matrix 

hold on
% For each point of the grid we plot an ellipse
for ii = 1:numel(X0)
    phi = mod((ii/20),2*pi);               % rotation by phi (in radian)
    XY  = rotmat(phi)*[a*cos(t);b*sin(t)]; % we apply the rotation to the ellipse equation
    x   = XY(1,:)+X0(ii);                  % Shift x with X0
    y   = XY(2,:)+Y0(ii);                  % Shift y with Y0
    fill(x,y,ii)                           % plot the ellipse
end
axis equal
```

And we obtain:

[image]

You just need to change the horizontal and vertical radius and `phi` according to `nx` and `ny`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. But I wanted the color to represent how elongated the oval in each point is and also, for non-elongated ovals (circles), I wanted to show them as circles. so both elongation is shown both by the color and actual elongation of the ovals. Is this possible?

Comment: so for example, dark blue shows circles and yellow shows elongated onal

Comment: The third parameter of the [`fill`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fill.html) function allows you to set the color. Check the doc.

Comment: Is it possible to add scale bar with the color to fill?

Comment: you're looking for `colorbar`.